# How to get Let's Encrypt Public, Private Key?

Tags: certificate

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx for my web server. I setup my website SSL with Let's Encrypt. And I want to get private, public key pair of Let's Encrypt.

Can someone point out where those files exist?

Comment: @techraf I already setup the ssl certificate. But, what I want to know is where is my public, private key pair.

Comment: I use ubuntu 16.04 with nginx setup. And I use ssl for let's encrypt. I want to get public vs private key pair from my ssl. How do I get it? @techraf

Comment: How you did it also affects where things may be located.  I use the `certonly` option (don't want 3rd party messing w/ my webserver config, although I use apache not nginx) and so my stuff ends up under `/etc/letsencrypt/example.com/live` which are just symlinks to the actual certificates (archive versions, LE keeps several old versions for you automatically)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Nginx you need to check the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory for the configuration file of your website (there might be multiple files).

Then you need to check their contents for configuration lines:

- `ssl_certificate` which will point to the certificate chain (`fullchain.pem`)
- `ssl_certificate_key` which will point to the private key (`privkey.pem`).

Finally you should use `openssl` command to extract the public key from the certificate chain file:

```
openssl rsa -in <path_to_privkey.pem> -pubout > key.pub
```

Comment: how to get the public key with `BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE` format. @techraf